# Catching 7z error in PHP - Wrong Password

Tags: php, error-handling, passwords, 7zip

I need to catch a wrong password error when running 7z in a php script so I can notify user PW needs to be changed.

```
$strCommandLine = "7z e '$zippath' -p'password' file.name";
system($strCommandLine);
```

System outputs the following on wrong password:

```
7-Zip [64] 16.02 : Copyright (c) 1999-2016 Igor Pavlov : 2016-05-21
p7zip Version 16.02 (locale=en_US.UTF-8,Utf16=on,HugeFiles=on,64 bits,32 CPUs AMD EPYC 7351P 16-Core Processor                (800F12),ASM,AES-NI)

Scanning the drive for archives:
1 file, 15072 bytes (15 KiB)

Extracting archive: /filepath/name.zip
ERROR: Wrong password--
Path =/filepath/name.zip
 : Type = zip
Physical Size = 15072
File.name
```

I have looked around and cannot see anything. Essentially looking for:

```
 if(badpassword)
{
send email to admin for PW change
}
```

To put in context, incoming files periodically change PW, but the PW refresh is not sent automatically, hence the requirement for notification.

Comment: If you read the manual about [system()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.system.php) it says: _"Returns **the last line** of the command output"_. Check if [shell_exec()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) works better, since it returns the full output. Then you should only need to check if the response contains the string: `ERROR: Wrong password`.

Comment: You could have a very good reason for this, but why not use the [ZIP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.zip.php) extension of PHP? The [setPassword()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.setpassword.php) method returns the boolean you're looking for.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware unfortunately, the 7z file is sent externally via email. It only opens in 7z.